# Is P = NP when solutions length is polynomially bounded by instance length?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np, search-problem

I'm currently reading the book "*P, NP, and NP-Completeness*" by Oded Goldreich. I'm currently reading a chapter that's concerned with the "search version" of the P-vs-NP-problem, that is if finding solutions is harder than checking the validity of solutions.

First, the book defines "polynomially bounded relations" as relations (between problem instances `x` and their solutions `y`) where there exists some polynomial `p` such that the length of the solution is polynomially bounded by the length of the related problem instance (that is `|y| <= p(|x|)`).

Both the search problem as well as the checking problem are then defined on such bounded relations.

Now I wonder: Doesn't polynomially bounding the length of possible solutions to a given instance mean that there are only polynomially many possible solution candidates, which, when given an algorithm `C` that checks a solution for its validity in polynomial time, implies that finding a solution can also be done in polynomial time by simply checking each of the possible solutions for its validity?

**This would mean that if I can efficiently check solutions of a problem for validity, then I can also efficiently find solutions to that problem. (So, basically P = NP)**

Is this conclusion - when only looking at polynomially bounded relations - true? (The book of course says that it's not. If I'd need to bet I'd also bet on the book and not on me...)

If not, **where is the error in my reasoning?**

Comment: I'd appreciate help with tagging; also please comment if the question is unclear due to lacking definitions.

Comment: Hint: there are $2^n$ many binary strings of length $n$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus oh my ... I definitely need more sleep. That's actually pretty obvious then ... Do you want to make a short answer out of that comment or shall I just delete the question?

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask

> Doesn't polynomially bounding the length of possible solutions to a given instance mean that there are only polynomially many possible solution candidates?

In fact, the number of binary strings of length $n^c$ is $2^{n^c}$, which is exponential in $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 3-SAT formula over $n$ variables and you can see that number of possible solution candidates is $\Omega(2^n)$, where as the size of each solution is polynomially bounded in the input size.

Comment: You want to say that the number of *potential* assignments is $\Omega(2^n)$ or $\Theta(2^n)$. An upper bound doesn't help here.

Comment: yes number of possible solutions candidates is $\Omega(2^n)$